# sort | uniq not working on different files

Tags: awk, sort, uniq

I have no idea why the command

```
sort filename.txt | uniq
```

is not working on this file: http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/32089/koran.gz.html

I have also used:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' koran.txt

perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' koran.txt
```

and no one seems working on this specific file. Any idea why?

Comment: If something "is not working" you should first of all explain what it is that is not working, i.e. what's your expectation and why. I'm not inclined to click on any strange link and inspect that file; provide sample data with your question, and explain what you want to achieve. Please try also to keep sample data consistent, not a html file and a txt file mixed. Finally the awk program just removes lines that are appearing more than once in the examined file, it's not sorting the data in the file.

Comment: _koran: C++ source, ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators_ ; convert your file to unix format then run `sort -u ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem has already been highlighted by `don_crissti` in his comment. He determined the file type by running:

```
file koran
```

... which outputs:

```
ASCII C++ program text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

You need to remove the `CR` (Carriage Return - hex value `\x0D`) characters which are present at the end of **some** lines in your input file. This `CR` is the first character of Microsoft Windows style end-of-line (CRLF). The second (MS) character is the `LF` (Line Feed). A single `LF` is the single valid character for a Unix style line terminator. Here is one way to remove the unwanted `CR` characters from your file:

```
sed 's/\x0D$//' koran | sort -u
```

`sort` has an option `-u` which "outputs only the first of an equal run", so you don't really need to pipe it on to `uniq`

---

Or, if your are sure that `CR` is the only *non-printing* character in your file, you can simply use sort's `-i` option to `ignore nonprinting` characters; - eg. `CR`

```
sort -iu koran
```

---

Update:
As per `@Francesco Mantovani`'s comment, *some* input lines - in other not previously mentioned files - also carry a trailing space before the CR. This is easily dealt with via the `sed` method:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+$//' male.txt female.txt | sort -u
```

As an aside, I spotted the difference by piping the output into `sed -n l` - As per `man sed` re the `l` command, "List out the current line in a *visually unambiguous* form".

Comment: Thank you, @Peter.O 'sort -u' is not working on this two files [http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/download/101267/arabicnames.zip]
The word "Zayn" is both in the female and male wordlist but if I do 'sort -u dict_arabicnames_male.txt dict_arabicnames_female.txt > total.txt' the word "Zayn" is repeted twice in the total.txt file