# Append words to wordlist with sort -u avoinding duplicata

Tags: sed, sort, dictionary

I have 2 txt file called one.txt with duplicata:

```
yesterday
yesterday
today
today
tomorrow
tomorrow
```

and the second txt called two.txt with duplicata:

```
mike
mike
paul
paul
tomorrow
tomorrow
```

Using the command `sort -u one.txt > total.txt` I can have an output file with:

```
today
tomorrow
yesterday
```

So I use `sort -u two.txt >> total.txt` to add append the second file to the same output file and I have as result:

```
today
tomorrow
yesterday
mike
paul
tomorrow
```

I do have twice the word "tomorrow". How to avoid it?

`sed 's/[[:space:]]+$//' one.txt two.txt | sort -u total.txt`

seems to be the solution but the problem appears every time I want to add another wordlist, exemple:

`sed 's/[[:space:]]+$//' three.txt | sort -u total.txt`

Comment: Thank you @Peter.O for suggesting the solution:
<code>sed 's/[[:space:]]\+$//' male.txt female.txt | sort -u</code> 
here: [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198770/sort-uniq-not-working-on-different-files?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re willing to have `total.txt` in sort order
(with `mike` and `paul` at the beginning),
you can do either of the following:

- `sort -u one.txt two.txt > total.txt` or
- `sort -u total.txt two.txt -o total.txt`

If you need to maintain the order (sorted contents of `one.txt` first,
followed by sorted contents of `two.txt`
***except for*** lines that were in `one.txt`), then do

- `sort -u two.txt | awk '!seen[$0]++' total.txt - > temp.txt; mv temp.txt total.txt`

which is equivalent to

- `(cat total.txt; sort -u two.txt) | awk '!seen[$0]++' > temp.txt; mv temp.txt total.txt`

i.e., take the contents of `total.txt`
(which are already sorted and deduped),
follow with the sorted, deduped contents of `two.txt`, and run them through
the [previously documented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/80216)
`awk` command to dedupe an unsorted file.

Comment: You should be familiar with the `awk '!seen[$0]++'` command; you cited it in [the question you asked yesterday](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198770/80216).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` plus `sponge` to safely overwrite an input file.
This allows you to use `total` as an input file - `sponge` is available in package `moreutils` (Ubuntu).

> sponge reads standard input and writes it  out  to    the 
>   specified  file.  Unlike  a  shell  redirect,    sponge soaks up all
>   its input before  opening  the    output  file.  This  allows for
>   constructing pipe‐    lines that read from and write to the same file.

```
file[0]=total; [[ -f "$file" ]] || touch "$file"
file[1]=any
file[2]=number 
file[3]=of
file[4]=files
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+$//' "${file[@]}" | sort -u | sponge "$file"
```

Note that the first item in a bash var array, `${file[0]}`, can be referenced and have its value set without the need to use an index, ie. `$file` (as I have done above - its just easier to type).
The `[[ -f total ]] || touch total` creates `total` if it doesn't already exit.
You can use any number of files - just increment the index number accordingly.
You can re-run the same set of files, and the contents of `total` will remain the same as the first run (for that set of files)

Instead of `sponge` you can just output to a temp file, then replace `total` with that temp file (but I like `sponge`)

Comment: The OP wiould understand why I used `sed`, but the general viewer of this answer may not - unless they followed the OP's reference in his comment to me about his previous question/answer. The reason is that _some_ of his input data lines have trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you @Peter.O I've found <code>sponge</code> very useful. I've also discovered that <code>sed -i</code> could also rewrite the input file